# How do I turn print into <p>

Tags: javascript, python, html, printing

### This is my script:

```
  <script>
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.printable
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    print("Random string of length", length, "is:", result_str)

get_random_string(8)
get_random_string(6)
get_random_string(4)
    </script>
```

---

I want to turn "    print("Random string of length", length, "is:", result_str)" Into text in a paragraph in my website, How do I do so?

Comment: Why's there a Python script in your script tag?

Comment: I dont really know html.... I need help with that also or just a way to convert it into js

Comment: You can run Python on the server. Use a library like Flask to use it for web processing.

Comment: how would i use python in html? like how you can use js

Comment: You should transpile it to JavaScript.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Python is a server side language. You can't run a script like you have above directly on the client / in the browser. You can use a library like Flask or Django on a server to render the output of your Python script to templates that are embedded in your HTML on the client side.

Comment: ohhh thank you, But I dont know how to turn it into js

Comment: You can add additional functionality to the fronted of your applicaton using JavaScript.

Comment: You can write the program so that it displays proper HTML code instead of plain text. However, no matter what you `print`, it cannot in any way interact with your web site. You need a *server* - a program that listens to HTTP requests from the Internet, and sends the HTML code, preceded by an HTTP header, back to the requester. This is a broad topic and you will need to use third-party tools and do a lot of research. We cannot possibly explain this in a single Stack Overflow question. For a high-level view, please consider asking on an actual *discussion forum* such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: I think I misunderstood - I thought you had mis-posted the code, and that the `<script>` tags were part of your attempt to format the code for posting here. If you meant that you are trying to use Python code *inside a web page*, that will not work - Javascript is the only language that will run in the browser. Aside from that, you need to write Javascript code that *manipulates the so-called DOM (Document Object Model)* - there is an equivalent to `print`, but it will only show up in your browser's debugging console. You are still way off from an answerable question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont really know html.... I need help with that also or just a way
> to convert it into js

If you just want to use javascript, in your html file like in your comment, then this is what I think you were trying to do:

```js
function get_random_str(length) {
    let result_str           = '';
    let characters       = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result_str += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
 charactersLength));
   }
   return result_str;
}
function display_text(elm, str) {

 document.getElementById(elm).innerHTML = str;
 
}

display_text('first', get_random_str(8));
display_text('second', get_random_str(6));
display_text('third', get_random_str(4));
```

```html
<p id="first">...</p>
<p id="second">...</p>
<p id="third">...</p>
```

If I misunderstood then my apologies

Answer (score 0):

I found a javascript library that let's you do write basically python instead of javascript; it's called Brython at [Brython website](https://brython.info/index.html).  Anyway, I bound your functions to some click event on some buttons. I used JSFiddle to run this sample. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.10.5/brython.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.10.5/brython_stdlib.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="brython()">

<script type="text/python">
## https://brython.info/index.html
## Python in place of javascript
from browser import document, alert, console
from browser.widgets.dialog import InfoDialog
import random
import string

def get_random_string(ev):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    length = ev.target.id
    length = length.replace("button_rand","")
    letters = string.printable
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(int(length)))
    ## Inspect your browser page and find console 'tab' at top or bottom...
    console.log(result_str)  
    alert(result_str)
    
def hello(ev):
    alert(ev.target.id)


document["button_alert"].bind("click", hello)
document["button_rand8"].bind("click", get_random_string)
document["button_rand6"].bind("click", get_random_string)
document["button_rand4"].bind("click", get_random_string)
</script>
<button id="button_alert">Say Hello</button>
<button id="button_rand8">Get random 8</button>
<button id="button_rand6">Get random 6</button>
<button id="button_rand4">Get random 4</button>

</body>
</html>
```